# Parse JSon String upto nth level

Tags: java, json, gson

Hello i have Json String which has depth upto N level following my Json String

```
{
           "id": 11,
           "name": "Release 5",
           "can_modify": true,
           "start_date": null,
           "due_date": null,
           "velocity_start_date": null,
           "capacity":
           {
               "duration": 0,
               "time_unit":
               {
                   "id": 0
               }
           },
           "release_notes": "",
           "status": 0,
           "is_active": true,
           "parent":
           {
               "id": 0
           },
           "release_type": 1,
           "children":
           [
               {
                   "id": 15,
                   "name": "V1",
                   "can_modify": true,
                   "start_date": "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z",
                   "due_date": null,
                   "velocity_start_date": null,
                   "capacity":
                   {
                       "duration": 0,
                       "time_unit":
                       {
                           "id": 0
                       }
                   },
                   "release_notes": "",
                   "status": 0,
                   "is_active": true,
                   "parent":
                   {
                       "id": 11
                   },
                   "release_type": 2,
                   "children":
                   [
                       {
                           "id": 16,
                           "name": "S1",
                           "can_modify": true,
                           "start_date": "2013-10-31T19:00:00Z",
                           "due_date": null,
                           "velocity_start_date": null,
                           "capacity":
                           {
                               "duration": 0,
                               "time_unit":
                               {
                                   "id": 0
                               }
                           },
                           "release_notes": "",
                           "status": 0,
                           "is_active": true,
                           "parent":
                           {
                               "id": 15
                           },
                           "release_type": 3,
                           "children":
                           [
                               {
                                   "id": 17,
                                   "name": "S1.1",
                                   "can_modify": true,
                                   "start_date": "2013-11-01T19:00:00Z",
                                   "due_date": null,
                                   "velocity_start_date": null,
                                   "capacity":
                                   {
                                       "duration": 0,
                                       "time_unit":
                                       {
                                           "id": 0
                                       }
                                   },
                                   "release_notes": "",
                                   "status": 0,
                                   "is_active": true,
                                   "parent":
                                   {
                                       "id": 16
                                   },
                                   "release_type": 3,
                                   "children":
                                   [
                                       {
                                           "id": 18,
                                           "name": "S.1.1.1",
                                           "can_modify": true,
                                           "start_date": "2013-11-02T00:00:00Z",
                                           "due_date": null,
                                           "velocity_start_date": null,
                                           "capacity":
                                           {
                                               "duration": 0,
                                               "time_unit":
                                               {
                                                   "id": 0
                                               }
                                           },
                                           "release_notes": "",
                                           "status": 11,
                                           "is_active": true,
                                           "parent":
                                           {
                                               "id": 17
                                           },
                                           "release_type": 3,
                                           "children":
                                           [
                                               {
                                                   "id": 20,
                                                   "name": "S1.1.1.1",
                                                   "can_modify": true,
                                                   "start_date": null,
                                                   "due_date": null,
                                                   "velocity_start_date": null,
                                                   "capacity":
                                                   {
                                                       "duration": 0,
                                                       "time_unit":
                                                       {
                                                           "id": 0
                                                       }
                                                   },
                                                   "release_notes": "",
                                                   "status": 0,
                                                   "is_active": true,
                                                   "parent":
                                                   {
                                                       "id": 18
                                                   },
                                                   "release_type": 3,
                                                   "children": null
                                               }
                                           ]
                                       }
                                   ]
                               }
                           ]
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

MY structure is like Release -> Childern -> Childern -> so on the level of sub children are N .. But i need them to be till 2 level Release -> Children thats it .
I want them to map  to my java classes using Gson MY Java class structure will be like this

```
Class release{
String id ;
String name ;
String start_date;
List<Children> children ;

}

Class Children{
String id ;
String name ;
String start_date;

}
```

Comment: Then what will you do with children element whose level is deeper than 2? discard them ?Since all children has their sub-children ,but you java class Children.java doesn't have members whose type is also Children , it is really a contradiction.

Comment: I wonder if your Java representation is incorrect. The JSON currently has a series of `Release` objects each with a single child (which is a release object) There are no `Children` objects in that JSON. Having said that, it looks like you're trying to represent a linked list in the JSON, so I would suggest a custom parser, or maybe reading everything into a series of release objects and then reading through those and adding all the objects into the list of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

You can can achieve it to nth level or 2 level like this, here are the Java classes for the for you json format

```
public class BaseModel {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String start_date;
    private boolean can_modify;
    private String due_date;
    private String velocity_start_date;
    private String Stringrelease_notes;
    private String status;
    private boolean is_active;
    private String release_type;
    // here getter/setter
}
```

**Release Class**

```
public class Release extends BaseModel {

    private List<Children> children;
    private Capacity capacity;
    private Parent parent;

    public List<Children> getChildren() { return children; }
    public void setChildren(List<Children> children) { this.children = children;}
    public Capacity getCapacity() { return capacity;}
    public void setCapacity(Capacity capacity) { this.capacity = capacity;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Release [capacity=" + capacity + ", parent=" + parent
                + ", getChildren()=" + getChildren() + ", getCapacity()="
                + getCapacity() + "]";
    }

}
```

**Children Class**

```
public class Children extends BaseModel {

    private List<Children> children;
    private Capacity capacity;
    private Parent parent;

    public List<Children> getChildren() {return children;}
    public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {this.children = children;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Children [capacity=" + capacity + ", parent=" + parent
                + ", getChildren()=" + getChildren() + "]";
    }
}
```

**Parent Class**

```
public class Parent {

    private int id;
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Parent [id=" + id + "]"; }
}
```

**Capacity Class**

```
public class Capacity {

    private int duration;
    private TimeUnit time_unit;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChildCapacity [duration=" + duration + ", time_unit="+ time_unit + "]";
    }
}
```

Just simply call

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
 Release release =gson.fromJson(Your_Json_String, Release.class);
release.getCapacity();
release.getParent();
release.getChildren(); // return main array below
// go inside for nested level lik as
release.getChildren().get(0).getChildren(); // return child array.
release.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren();// return nested child array of above level
```

If you want to retrieve particular child of parent then you need to implement recursion your self after desalinizing you json.

Enjoy! :)